# Why are the names of the letters different across languages using the Latin script?

Tags: terminology, alphabets

I have noticed that the Spanish alphabet has the 26 letters + the consonant ñ, which is pronounced like the "ny" in "canyón". But out of the remaining 26 letters, I have noticed that the consonants have different names from the names in English. Why can't all the 26 letters be given universal names for all the Latin script languages?

Comment: This has been migrated from https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/34715/why-does-spanish-have-different-names-for-the-letters-of-the-alphabet-from-english?

Comment: If you think about it, it makes just as much sense for Spanish to have different names for its letters as it does for Spanish to have different words for _paper_ and _pencil_. We naturally expect words in one language to be different from words in another, and the names of the letters are words in the languages they write. Though most European languages would use the same names for their cardinal vowels - _a, e, i, o, u_. All the European languages except English pronounce them and name them the same: ah, eh, ee, o, oo. But English changed the sounds and thus the names: eh, ee, eye, o, you.

Comment: Er… the letters nearly all have the same names in Spanish as in English (with minor differences, but that’s just because they’re different languages). Jay/jota, v/uve and double-u/doble uve are the only ones that have any real difference; the rest are essentially the same, just pronounced according to the phonemes of either language.

Comment: Apparently, if I tell Siri or Cortana the sound used by "ay" in "day", it is interpreted as the letter "e".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why can't all the 26 letters be given universal names for all the Latin languages?

They used to, in fact! Well…mostly.

Back in the days of the Roman empire, [there were mostly consistent names for the letters of the alphabet](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/733/406): *ā, bē, cē, dē, ē* and so on. There was a bit of variation in some of them, like *ef* versus *effe*, *hȳ* versus *ȳ-graeca*, and *ex* versus *ix*, but for the most part they were consistent.

But languages change over time. At one point, for example, English shifted all of its "long E" sounds from IPA `/e:/` (as in *caf**é***) to IPA `/i:/` (as in *mach**i**ne*). And this affected the letter names they'd borrowed from Latin: that's how we got "bee, dee, ee, gee" versus Spanish *be, de, e, ge*, etc.

Other differences might have originated from variations within Latin, such as the *ef* versus *effe* mentioned by Roman grammarians. Some letters didn't exist within Latin, such as *W*, *Ñ*, and *J*, so those were given names later. The letter *Z* was renamed in American English, by analogy with *C*, *D*, *E*, and so on. But most of the differences can be traced back to English changing all its long vowels somewhere around the fifteenth century, a process called the "Great Vowel Shift".

Answer (score 3):

The main reason is that it would be impossible to agree on a name. Is "z" to be called "tset", "zed", "zee", "zeta" and so on? What about the letters that are *not* used in English – what do we call ç?

We have different names for letters because names for letters developed long ago from different sources. The Latin name for "z" is based on the Greek name which is based on the Semitic name; the letter "f" derives from a Semitic letter for [w], called *waw*. [Here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/732/what-are-the-classical-names-of-the-letters-of-the-latin-alphabet) is an account of the Latin letter names, which explains much about current names.

Comment: is zeta based on the semitic name? The Hebrew is zayin, with Aramaic and Arabic agreeing on zayn (likely also the pronunciation in early Hebrew before the áy > áyi change). The t appears to be a Greek innovation, presumably by analogy to beta, zeta, eta, theta, and iota

Comment: I believe you are right, @Tristan.

Comment: @Tristan yep, similarly, Alpha comes from Aleph, Beta from Beth, Gamma from Gimel, Iota from Yod, Lambda from Lamed, etc.

Answer (score -3):

It happened because of the splitting of the Roman Empire. Before that, the letters were called "[a~æ], [be], [se], [de], [e~ɛ], [ef]/[efe], etc. . ." and were pretty consistent, other than a few minor differences. Note that at this time the letters denoted ⟨J⟩, ⟨W⟩, ⟨X⟩ and a few others did not exist. After the Roman empire split, things stayed the same for a while.

However, the letters ⟨J⟩, ⟨W⟩, and ⟨X⟩ where introduced into the then 23 letter Latin alphabet. Unlike most European languages, the Spaniards had no need for ⟨J⟩ for the sound [j], which they were already representing with ⟨Y⟩ and ⟨LL⟩. They did however have a use for it as [h], since the letter ⟨H⟩ was either silent or marking aspiration in most contexts. They called it [hotə] which made a lot of sense. When encountering ⟨W⟩, they had already split ⟨U⟩ and ⟨V⟩ so the called it [ðoble.ve], and they most retained the original name of ⟨X⟩, calling it [eki].

Meanwhile, English had it's own changes. All [eː] sounds shifted to [i] sounds during the great vowel shift, we had no use of ⟨J⟩ as [j], so instead used it for [d͡ʒ] and called it [d͡ʒej]. When English speakers encountered ⟨W⟩, we'd not yet split ⟨U⟩ and ⟨V⟩. As a result, we called it [dəbəl.ju]. Finally, we used ⟨X⟩ to represent the common consonant cluster [ks~kz], and called it [ekz] accordingly.

After a few more small changes, it reached the point where we are today.

As nice as it'd be, such standardization is unfortunately impossible. It would require asking about two billion people to start completely changing everything about their alphabet. It would require completely changing early education, and forcing the changes in a legal context.

If such standardization was possible, we'd all be speaking Esperanto.

Comment: This gets a lot wrong. <x> was part of the standard Roman alphabet representing /ks/ and called /eks/ (whence the English pronunciation [eks], with Spanish [ekis] being a reborrowing adjusted to account for Spanish phonotactics. <j> originated as a variant of <i> (partially descended from the i-longa <ꟾ> sometimes used to write /ī/ in Latin. With the introduction of the printing press its use became more standardised for the reflexes of Vulgar Latin /j/ (including those from /i/ or /e/ before another vowel).

Comment: At the time <j> was introduced, Spanish yeísmo had not taken place so <ll> was still a lateral [ʎ]. Spanish <j> is also not used for [h] in most varieties, but for [x] (in varieties with an [h] it is typically an allophone of /s/ in coda position, although there are a small number with [h] for /x/); at the time <j> was introduced it was probably still pronounced [(d)ʒ] (which only later backed and devoiced to [x]). English got its pronunciation and name of <j> from Old Norman French (where it was at the time pronounced [dʒ] as it is still in English).

Comment: additionally, the Spanish name for <w> is not standardised and all of uve doble, ve doble, doble ve, doble u (the first three meaning "double v", the last meaning "double u") are found

Comment: @Tristan in most dialects it's pronounced [eki]. You are correct that what I transcribed as [h] is more often pronounced as [x], I did this for simplicity (many people see [x] and don't mentally hear a velar fricative. Similar thing with [j], but that was necessary). I am aware of ⟨J⟩ being a descendant of ⟨I⟩, but I didn't mention it to avoid over-complicating things. I used the name for ⟨W⟩ typically taught to non-native Spanish speakers, though you are correct that people call it many different things. I was not aware of ⟨J⟩ having been pronounced as [dʒ] in Spanish, which is interesting.

Comment: the underlying form is /ekis/ in all dialects. Many dialects (roughly half of Latin America by area, the Southern half of Spain, and the canaries, but not in mainland Africa or the Philippines) aspirate coda /s/ to [h] giving a pronunciation [ekih] in isolation or before a voiceless consonant (before a vowel the coda /s/ is still [s], and before a voiced consonant it is [ɦ]). Total loss of coda s is much more unusual but is found in Honduras, el Salvador, and Southeastern Spain. https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:S_aspiration_in_Spanish.png

Comment: using [h] for [x] is not clarifying, it is incorrect (except in Southern Spain and much of the Caribbean where <j> is pronounced [h]). The IPA exists for a reason, and deviating from it in a linguistic context to conform to laymen's expectations only causes more confusion. I don't know what's most commonly taught as the name of <w>, but I mentioned it because I (in the UK) was consistently taught "uve doble" rather than "doble ve"

Comment: I will attempt to more carefully analyze the phonology.